# Should the "treasury" tag be renamed to make it specific to the U.S., as it has been used so far?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the [treasury](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasury) tag for? I just saw it on a handful of questions.

It looks like it is being used to refer to the *U.S. Department of the Treasury*.  But, "treasury" itself is a generic word without meaning ascribed specifically to the U.S.

Is there an alternative we could use that doesn't confuse?  What about [us-treasury](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-treasury)?

Answer (score 2):

What is the practical use of "treasury" as a term here? As a generic term, it seems too general for us. From this perspective, I have a hard time seeing more than a few questions that would be practical enough for this site while using a generic "treasury" tag. That is, most economics questions of that sort would be keenly focused on treasuries as generic entities; that seems like "hypothetical country." It seems that a small trickle of questions of this sort may be an exception that proves the rule.

From the high-level view, yes I agree that they are two different terms and we should have a specific tag for "us-treasury."  From the practical perspective, I have a concern about confusion and the suggestion that more open-ended, economics style questions are acceptable.  After all, we would have a generic "treasury" tag.

What are some of the practical questions for a generic "treasury" tag?

tl;dr

I see little practical use of a generic "treasury" tag.  To my mind, the practical questions would be related to a specific jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0):

Treasury is a generic tag and I think we should leave it at that ...
Its possible that its been frequently used in the context of US as by and large most of the audience on this site is interested in US Treasury ... however as the site grows it should balance out the usage and would be used for other countries as well ...